# Rails 3 create method redirect to index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having an issue where my article_controller.rb's create method is redirecting to the index when the article.save fails due to invalid input by the user. The articles creation url is /articles/new but when the submit fails, I'm redirected to /articles. The form is still available in /articles exactly as it was on /articles/new. The desired behavior would be to return to the /articles/new with whatever the user may have entered repopulated in the form. Is there a way to do this? Here are some of the code snippets to illustrate what's going on.

Here is the article new method:

```
def new
    @article = Article.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

Here is the article create method:

```
def create
    @article = current_user.articles.new(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }
      else
        format.html { render 'new' }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
.....
<% end %>
```

I'm eventually hoping to get this working with a :remote => :true call in the form_for, but just want to get it working first the way it is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
format.html { render :action => "new" }
```

Comment: I believe this is the right code, and behind the scenes it *is* rendering the new.html.erb file, which calles in my form, but, the RESTful url is still coming up as /articles, and not /articles/new. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: rendering a template is "just renderign the page" without executing the controller code/method(new). http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313

Comment: the article in that link is correct in saying that i want to use render and not redirect_to, since in this situation the create method is re-rendering the new.html.erb without losing what the user entered. redirect_to would lose the user entered values so that's not what i want.

Comment: The reason why the url is /articles is because when you hit the submit button, you called the create action which has a url /articles but with method post, and when the saving failed, you rendered the new action without redirect, so the url didn't change /articles with method post. Is this an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

And if you are using Rails 3+, try writing your controller something like this DRY.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html

 def new
   @article = Article.new
   respond_with @article
 end

 def create
   @article = Article.new(params[:article])
   @article.save
   respond_with(@article)
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! The only problem i can see with this approach is that I'd have to drastically change my controller by changing all the methods that have respond_to do |format|. I haven't used respond_to in the way you're describing above. If I used your suggestion I wouldn't then know how to check the formats for xml, js, json, etc... could I still have conditionals for format, like "if format.js ..."? Thanks I will try this, but I have a feeling there is a way to make what I have work... Will the respond_with param send me back to /articles/new and *not* /articles if @article.save returns false?

Comment: "Will the respond_with param send me back to /articles/new and not /articles if @article.save returns false?" Yes

Comment: If you want custom XML,JSON for your controller methods, you can use RABL https://github.com/nesquena/rabl gem available

Comment: raj: so i looked into your suggestion and found this article: http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/10/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-default-restful-rendering . this was actually really helpful in my making my controller DRYer as you suggested, but I am still having the same issue. (in response to using respond_with and not respond_to)

Comment: raj: I am finding that it is not the case when you answer "Yes" to "Will the respond_with param send me back to /articles/new and not /articles if article.save returns false?". I am still ending up at the url /articles and not /articles/new when the create method fails to on @article.save. I can't figure it out.

Comment: rendering a template is "just renderign the page" without executing the controller code/method(new). http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313

Comment: hey if you don't mind adding to my reputation here i'd appreciate it, i can even chat or mark your answers as helpful or even correct.

Comment: i think the behavior is all correct, and as the link you posted (http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313) states: "if your action is new, rails will render the view for new: new.html.erb." this is true, it's happening, but the url is still showing /articles and not /articles/new... do you know the reason for that?

Comment: if you render something it will not go to routes.rb, instead will be rendered directly. If there is routes.rb not involved no url will be changed. I hope it will clear your confusion

Comment: yes, it's a little bit hard to wrap my head around, but yeah, it looks like the form is posting to /articles so it makes sense that the url ends up being /articles and not /articles/new. it would be nice if it were /articles/new though. thanks for the help, still open to suggestions...

Comment: If the answer is useful please rate it :)

Comment: like i said before, i need you to add to my reputation because i'm a new user, then i could add to your rating.